# string formatting escape using rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am trying out rpy2 to write a R-function in Python(2.7) and I have one function in R factorwars that saves the index of every element in methods that contains the string 'reg':

```
from rpy2.robjects import r, pandas2ri
import rpy2.robjects as rob 
import pandas as pd
pandas2ri.activate()

rstring="""
function(methods){
factorvars=which(methods %in% 'reg')
}
"""
rfunc=rob.r(rstring)
new_data=rfunc(methods)
```

the rstring is infact a bit longer, and I have tried using '%sin%' %% after the string as well as \%in%, but Python keep interpreting it as %i and asks for an integer. Any idea on how I can either escape %in% in Python or write a similar function with % in R.

edit: included more code, imports and functions. Much of the problem is that when I change the code, the R code will be wrong. Any python function for this_is_only_string('some string') that will overwrite the formatting perhaps?

%%in%% gives error message:

```
  <text>:9:41: unexpected 'in'
8:         fact = c('polyreg', 'logreg')
9:         factorvars=which(method_array %%in
```

Answer (score 0):

If `%` is being interpreted as a `printf` style directive, try doubling the % signs: `%%in%%`

Comment: I changed the question, hope it is more clear. %%in%% is not working either unfortunately.

Comment: That's a completely different error. Doubling the `%` sign stopped `%i` being interpreted as a formatting directive, which is what your question was. Can't help with the incorrect R syntax.

Comment: But your escaping problem is solved and you put that in the title too.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be working on this end:

```
>>> from rpy2 import robjects
>>> rstring = """ function(x) { x %in% c("a", "b") } """
>>> robjects.r(rstring)("a")
Out[6]: 
R object with classes: ('logical',) mapped to:
<BoolVector - Python:0x7f962c089608 / R:0x2919c88>
[       1]
```